# Draw mask on image with transparency

Tags: image, matlab, octave

In Matlab/Octave (`Image` package) is it possible to draw a slightly transparent coloured rectangle over an image region?

For example; I want to draw a red rectangle (alpha/opacity of 0.5) over the top left corner of an image.

```
pkg load image;
pkg load signal;

i = imread('foo.jpg');

% Somehow draw a transparent rectangle over the top left of the image

imshow(i);
```

Comment: You should if possible explicitely say if you want a solution for GNU Octave or Matlab. There is not such "Matlab/Octave" thing. And yes, it's possible, just add a rectangle to the third dimension of i

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hold on` and the property [`'AlphaData'`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image-properties.html#property_d0e458977) to draw a transparent overlay as follows:

```
image = rand(100); % a random image
imshow(image); % show the image

% create the red overlay
red = zeros(100, 100, 3);
red(:, :, 1) = 1;

% create the alpha channel with the right transparency
alpha = zeros(100); % everywhere completely transparent
alpha(1:50, 1:50) = 0.5; % except for the top left corner

hold on
h = imshow(red); % show the overlay
set(h, 'AlphaData', alpha); % apply the transparency
```

[image]